# Why throwing exception is not working when parameter is null?

Tags: java

I created a method which remove the students from a HashMAP. it should throw an exception when the id is null. Did somebody know why it is not working?

```java
public void deleteStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id)  {
        Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate, gender, id);

        if (students.containsKey(id)) {
            students.remove(id);
        }
        if (students.containsKey(id == null)) {
              throw new NullPointerException("The student does not exist");
        }
    }
```

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

```
    StudentRepository myStudent = new StudentRepository();
    myStudent.addStudent("St","Rt","0742", "1993.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1930303");
    myStudent.addStudent("Sr","Ro","0742", "1994.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1940304");
    myStudent.addStudent("Se","Rb","0742", "1995.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1950305");
    myStudent.addStudent("Sm","Re","0742", "1996.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1950306");
    myStudent.deleteStudent("Str","Rob","0742", "1992.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "null");
    myStudent.addStudent("Sr","Ro","0742", "1994.03.04", PersonGender.MALE, "1940304");
    myStudent.displayStudents();


}
```

}

Comment: Isn't it just `if (id == null) { throw new .... } `?

Comment: And it seems like you'd want that *before* you try to use `id`.

Comment: it has the same behaviour, no exception is throwed

Comment: 1) Please, add code where `students` is created/read, currently it's impossible to understand what's in that variable.
2) `containsKey(id == null)` is actually the same as `containsKey(True)`, if `students` is just a set of id's, you can replace it with `containsKey(null)`

Comment: I added what you requested

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public void deleteStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id)  {
        Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate, gender, id);

        if (id == null) {
              throw new NullPointerException("ID is null");
        }

        if (students.containsKey(id)) {
            students.remove(id);
        }
        else {
            throw new NullPointerException("The student does not exist");
        }

    }
```

**Note:**

1. Assuming if `students` do not contain key then throw an exception. Hence added `else` statement.
2. Also, checked passed `id` initially. if it is not found then throw an exception. You can modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Horrible suggestion! Why should NPE be thrown for a missing student? NPE should strictly be thrown for `null` references. You should suggest to create a custom business exception and throw the same instead of misusing NPE.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash you are right. We can do a lot with above code. However Motive was to solve the problem and guide the user to move ahead as per his/her written code

Answer (score 1):

You should check the correctness of input parameters before using them. This follows a typical [guard pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)).

```
my_function(some params) {
  if (precondition not met) { //the guard
    error handling;
  }
  business logic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `Student.id` is in `String` format, you should check for null by using `equals()`.
Like this:

```
public void deleteStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String birthDate, PersonGender gender, String id)  {
    Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, birthDate, gender, id);

    if (students.containsKey(id)) {
        students.remove(id);
    }
    if (id.equals("null")) {
        throw new NullPointerException("The student does not exist");
    }
}
```